# How can I view http requests made from my system (not web browser)?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, utility

How can I see the http requests originating from my Windows system.
Is there any utility (windows/visual studio/command line) to do that, which shows exactly like the Network pane in console of a web browser.

The scenario - 
I am debugging a third party code using Visual Studio which hits an API. Now I want to see what request it makes. I know Wireshark but it shows the encrypted packets.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler is the utility for it!